# Solution for an app to lock user screen on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

My manager is looking to create a desktop application with C# that basically locks the user screen after some minutes of inactivity and shows a Login form that is connected with a SQL database in the back-end. Can I achieve that on Windows or it's a security issue locking the user screen completely and disabling `Ctrl + Alt + Del` so he can't bypass the login form? The point of this idea is that we can extend functionality of the app in the future (like an internet cafe app). Can someone redirect me to the correct path/docs/tutorial on how to do something like this?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for windows kiosk mode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app - afaik you cannot lock windows completely from an app but... you can tell windows to allow only a single app and that's what is called "kiosk mode".

Comment: Sounds like you might want to create a Custom Credential Provider https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/credential-providers-in-windows and then simply set the screensaver to auto-lock

Comment: How are you planning to block Ctrl+Alt+Del?